# How can i see path in windows for docker container? Mine is giving root@default:/home/some file name,where i can see this path in windows

Tags: bash, docker, bin

Hey i'm trying to find out the path where i can see the file in windows. I install docker toolbox in D drive, But when i give command "docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash then it redirect me to root@default:/home/application-name.

[image]

Now my Question is where can i see home/application-name file path in windows?

Answer (score 0):

That path is not visible to host system as its on a virtual disk mounted on docker. The Virtual Disk itself is a file

Comment: is there any command in docker to see that file in container??

Comment: Not sure if there is a command for that. But you can check for all ".qcow2" extension files in ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/. Alternatively here is the link that can help you further https://forums.docker.com/t/host-path-of-volume/12277/11